# Java 8 Parallel Streams and Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

**Under what conditions (if any), would it make sense to use Java 8 Parallel Streams in the code for a Hadoop MapReducer reducer?**

This question is predicated on the observation that exactly one reducer instance is created for each mapped key, and the assumption that each reducer instance is assigned to exactly one thread.

Thus, it stands to reason that if the set of mapped values for any particular mapped key is sufficiently large, then the runtime of a job could be improved by introducing intra-reducer parallelism (in addition to the inter-reducer parallelism already provided by the framework).

However, I am unsure how other factors would affect this behavior in practice, and so whether or not this conclusion is generalizable enough to be practical, or whether real-world conditions make it too dependent on some other specific conditions to be actually useful (e.g. something like the interaction between the number of other jobs in the queue and the number of processors in the cluster).

---

*NOTE:  As I am a student, I do not have a readily available cluster to test this on myself.*

Comment: *I am unsure how other factors would affect this behavior in practice, and so whether or not this conclusion is generalizable enough to be practical* That is a very broad question. Part of the answer is [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law), but determining how much speed up is possible with additional parallelism is something you do have to verify against configuration, data and hardware.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Would additional parallelism even make sense?  Or in an environment that has a constant flow of jobs (for example), would Hadoop already ensure that all processors are being used anyway (spread among jobs), and so trying to manually code more parallelism than what Hadoop already provides would be ineffective / counterproductive?

Comment: ^^^ that's more what my question is about than "how much speedup"

Comment: I know that is your question. Read my first comment again. It's like asking how long a train takes to go from New York to Boston. Without knowing how fast the train is...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch No, you appear to be misunderstanding my question.  I don't care specifically "how long."  I am asking in the abstract what are the most significant factors that would affect the "how long" in practice (i.e. that I may not know about) and how to judge between them (e.g. speed of train, length of trip, number of stops on trip, number of other trains sharing the same track by time of day, etc.).  It's like the difference between asking "what is the specific value of `x!`" and "how do I evaluate any `x!` in general".

Comment: No. How do I calculate any function (in general) and how long will it take (in general). Notice I'm only commenting, and no one is answering.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch You're still misconstruing it.  But in any case, if you choose to interpret it as "how long will it take in general," then it's still a valid question in terms of what are the most significant factors in practice that affect "how long it will take in general."

Comment: The variables that will affect performance are *generally*: configuration (of your data node, the operating system, the cluster software, the version thereof, processor affinity), data (the data itself, how it is structured, compression, partitions) and hardware (how much memory, how many cpus and cores are on each node, network bandwidth).